# Selecting value from drop down in selenium from suggested values

Tags: java, selenium

Would it be possible to select value from drop down if user is entering only initials of the value.

Say " I have 2 values in drop down "Claim" and "Policy" and if I type "C" in drop down it should show "claims" and user can select it.

Not able to build logic for this.

Comment: which language ?

Comment: Would it be possible in Java

Comment: use [`String#startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

Comment: would it be possible for you to share some code. I am not able to start.

Comment: @VinodKumar Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSelector"));
  List<WebElement> options= select.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
  for(WebElement option :options){
   if("Add Claim Documents".equals(option.getText())){
    option.click();
   }
  }

Comment: i am trying it in another way

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one ,it may help you  
//searchValue=C, P ,full text.
  public boolean selectValueFromDropDown(String searchValue) {      
                // select dropdown box 
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));
                element.click();
                element.sendKeys(searchValue);
                element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSelector" value="" aria-invalid="true" type="text"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField">Enter or select an entry template</span><input name="ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSelector" value="" type="hidden"></div>